# 960gs grid in grid

Tags: css, 960.gs

How do I make more grids inside another grid?

For eg.

I have a 2 column with 2 or more columns inside the left one:

```
------------------   ---------
|                |   |       |
|  ______   ___  |   |       | 
|  |     |  |  | |   |       |
|  |_____|  |__| |   |       |
|                |   |       |
|________________|   |_______|
```

If I do (container_24):

```
<div class="grid_16">
    <div class="prefix_3 grid_6 suffix_2"></div>
    <div class="grid_4 suffix_1"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid_8">
</div>
```

This will cause problems due to the padding on the grids. Is there to reset the system so I can use a mini grid inside another grid?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have a set of grids inside a grid you use the `.alpha` and `.omega` classes.

```
<div class="container_24">
    <div class="grid_16">
        <div class="prefix_3 grid_6 suffix_2 alpha"></div>
        <div class="grid_4 suffix_1 omega"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_8">
</div>
```

`.alpha` - removes the margin-left

`.omega` - removes the margin-right

Answer (score 0):

When I run into something like this, I generally take one of two approaches:

1. Change the size of the inner-most
   grid. In your case, change `prefix_3`
   to `prefix_2`, `grid_6` to `grid_5`, or
   `suffix_2` to `suffix_1`.
2. Overwrite the styles in your own
   stylesheet by targeting that
   specific element and reducing the
   padding.